On airplanes with bleed air anti-ice systems, why is only the leading edge of the wing heated? What happens in freezing rain?
For example, if the plane is ascending or descending and there's freezing rain, surely by gravity the freezing/supercooled rain will also land on parts of the wing aft of the leading edge, will it not?

In the boundary layer, the airflow moves parallel to the wing surface:

The vertical velocity of the aircraft doesn't change the direction of the flow, it remains parallel to the wing surface.

The vertical velocity of the falling rain, 10 to 30 km/h, is negligible in this context, hence moisture moves in the same direction than air.


However there is a line where air doesn't move: The stagnation pressure line, which is on the leading edge (S):

Ice crystals accumulate here, and supercooled water hitting this line freezes. In Kutta condition, there is a symmetrical stagnation line at the trailing edge, but water cannot hit the trailing edge, the flow is moving away from it.
The pressure gradient influences ice formation too: The production of ice from water is accelerated by a pressure decrease. Along the airfoil, pressure decreases from the leading edge, and increases again after a some distance until reaching the trailing edge.
Icing is significant only at the leading edge. This is true for the empennage too, but empennage leading edges are thinner than wings, preventing ice to really build up and become a problem (apart from horns which may be electrically heated to prevent locking).

Droplets that don't impinge on the surface near the stagnation point on the leading edge tend to be carried around parallel to the surface without making contact.  However, what does actually strike the leading edge surface can flow along the surface and re-freeze where the heated area terminates. This is called "runback ice".
Some wings can tolerate runback ice and some can't. If the wing can't, you use an "evaporative" anti-ice system where the leading edge is heated above the boiling point of water, so droplets that strike evaporate away instead of running along the surface. With an evaporative system you generally don't get any icing behind the leading edge unless it's at a severe icing level, in which case you have to get out of it ASAP.
